# How to add custom color theme in nivo chart settings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nivo-react

I am using Nivo charts in one of my projects and I have implemented nivo chart settings as they have implemented them in their website.
However, I wanted to add a few of my own custom color theme options additional to what nivo provides.
For more clarity, I am attaching this screenshot

[image]

Right now,  we import colors from nivo package as

```
import {
    categoricalColorSchemeIds,
    divergingColorSchemeIds,
    sequentialColorSchemeIds,
    colorSchemes,
} from '@nivo/colors'
```

now I read somewhere that we can inject our custom object as color theme, can anyone help me show as how it would be possible if for ex I want to add new theme with name CustomTheme with colors of "#000, #fff ,#ff0000".
How would we do that, any help would be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20):

Do:

```
colors={['#111111', '#222222']}
colorBy="index"
```

Comment: I don't think you need `colorBy` property and it doesn't even exist on all charts

Comment: I think so, this is the issue:
https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/945

Answer (score 0):

Moreover. After voting up @Tania answer which works perfectly (without any colorBy) I found out you can recall CSS variables in the array so you have support for light and dark theme straight forward.
Like

```
const customColors = [
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--severity-low'),
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(
    '--severity-medium'
  ),
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(
    '--severity-high'
  ),
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(
    '--severity-critical'
  ),
]
```